# Debug a C# dll called from C++ (with Mono embedded)

Tags: c#, c++, mono, cppsharp

I have a runtime written in C++ (with Mono embedded) which calls functions in a dll written in C#  using `mono_jit_exec` and `mono_runtime_invoke`. The glue code is generated with [CppSharp](https://github.com/mono/CppSharp) - which I don't think is relevant here, but just to mention.

So far all good, I can communicate in both directions.

What I want now is to debug the C# code only, using Visual Studio (I'm using the version 2019 on macOS). So in my C# project, I went to *Run Configuration* and selected the *Start external program* option pointing to my C++ assembly. After that, I've set some breakpoints, but when I run the C# project in Debug mode, they're never triggered.

Why is not working - is there something else that needs to be done? Is it because Mono is involved?

Comment: Because VS only has its .NET Framework and .NET Core compatible debuggers, not working for Mono. In a day like this (Mono is going away), you probably should try to embed .NET Core https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/netcore-hosting

Comment: Why do you say that Mono is going away? It seems like an active project. Besides that, I need to expose my C++ methods to C# and call them directly using `DllImport("__Internal")`, and .NET Core doesn't provide such functionality.

Comment: .NET 5 is going to be the unified option, after .NET Core merges with Mono CLR. The other components of Mono, if not migrated to .NET 5, are going away quickly. MonoDevelop has already reached its end, and other indicators are there. So if you want to avoid wasting your efforts, start with .NET Core today.

Comment: I see your point, and it's definitely something to take into account since I'm starting with this integration now. The thing is: Is there a way to call host's methods directly from C# using .NET Core like I'm doing with Mono? I don't want to go off-topic so I've created a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63081509/call-c-host-methods-directly-from-c-sharp-using-net-core).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the answer is that is currently not supported.

A workaround would be to do remote debugging using a plugin for Visual Studio or Visual Studio Code, as [Unity does](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeDebugging.html).

One available extension is [VS Code Mono Debug](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-mono-debug), which is based on the [SDB: Mono Soft Debugger Client](https://github.com/mono/sdb).