# Call C++ (host) methods directly from C# using .NET Core

Tags: c#, c++, .net-core, interop

Embedding .NET Core into a C++ application you can call managed methods like it's described in [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/netcore-hosting#create-a-host-using-nethosth-and-hostfxrh) with [this sample](https://github.com/dotnet/samples/tree/master/core/hosting/HostWithHostFxr). You can even send a function pointer as a parameter for the managed code to call back into the host.

But is there any way to invoke unmanaged methods directly, without using callbacks? With Mono, you can achieve this using P/Invoke and `DllImport("__Internal")` which will search for the symbols in the host assembly directly. So in this way expose you can expose your C++ functionality to C# and use the later as a scripting language. **Is there a way to accomplish the same with .NET Core?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it by creating an entry point and then calling the methods using Reflection.

Here's an example:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

public class MyType
{
    public string CallMe(int i, float f)
    {
        return $"{i} and {f}";
    }
}

class Program
{
    public static string CallArbitraryMethod(string typeName, string methodName, string[] paramNames, object[] arguments)
    {
        // create the type
        var type = Type.GetType(typeName);
        if (type == null) return null;

        // create an instance using the default constructor
        var ctor = type.GetConstructor(new Type[0]);
        if (ctor == null) return null;
        var obj = ctor.Invoke(null);
        if (obj == null) return null;

        // construct an array of parameter types
        var paramTypes = new Type[ paramNames.Length ];
        for(int i=0; i<paramNames.Length; i++)
        {
            switch(paramNames[i].ToUpper())
            {
                case "INT": paramTypes[i] = typeof(int); break;
                case "FLOAT": paramTypes[i] = typeof(float); break;
                // etc.
                default: return null;
            }
        }

        // get the target method
        var method = type.GetMethod(methodName, paramTypes);
        if (method == null) return null;

        // invoke and return
        return (string)method.Invoke(obj, arguments);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var result = CallArbitraryMethod("MyType", "CallMe", new string[] {"int", "float"}, new object[] {5, 10.5f});
        Console.WriteLine($"{result}");
    }
}
```

More information [on this GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/40203).